# Powershell Script creation by script with transfer of variables

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a new script over the current script, but he doesn't want to enter the $ passwd variable in the new script. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem?

here is my Code

```
 "Install-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Domain-services -IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature"| add-content $datei
"$passwd = read-host ""geben Sie das Sicherheitspassword für den Admin ein"" -AsSecureString"| add-content $datei
```

And that is the script which is then given to me. As you can see, the variable is missing

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name AD-Domain-services -IncludeManagementTools -IncludeAllSubFeature
= read-host "geben Sie das Sicherheitspassword für den Admin ein" -AsSecureString
```

Comment: use single quotes: `'$passwd = read-host ""geben Sie das Sicherheitspassword für den Admin ein"" -AsSecureString'  | add-content $datei`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier if you put the code inside a [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) and write that to $datei in one go?

Comment: Thank you very much for the single quotes I didn't think of. Has now worked